# HTML Select Box To Check Specific Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I've been lurking for a while, and finally need to ask a question!

I'm testing a select form as follows:

```
    <form id='list'><br>
            1<input type='checkbox' value='1' />
            2<input type='checkbox' value='2' />
            3<input type='checkbox' value='3' />
            4<input type='checkbox' value='4' />
            5<input type='checkbox' value='5' />
            CheckThese<input type='checkbox' name='checkthese' onclick='checkThese()'><br>
    </form>
```

And corresponding JavaScript as:

```
    <script language='JavaScript'>
        function checkThese () {
            var values = ['1', '2', '4', '5'];
            $("#list").find('[value=' + values.join('], [value=') + ']').prop("checked", true);

        }   
    </script>
```

For some reason, when I check "CheckThese" checkbox in the form, it doesn't select option 1, 2, 4, and 5..

Can someone please help me get it work?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/QGr7R/. Where is your function located in regard to your document?

Comment: Which jquery version are you using? Any error in console?

Comment: Hello everyone! Thank you guys very much for the input so far. I'm using RoR and I put the codes in the original question plus google cdn directly inside _form.html.erb. And it still doesn't work like demo'ed in jsfiddle above. Please help again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works provided you link jquery src??

add the following to your code : (using google cdn)

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm still very new to Ruby on Rails and jquery. I've added google cdn to my code (_form.html.erb), and unfortunately it still doesn't work. :/